# Copy data from Word to Outlook body keeping formatting

Tags: vba, outlook

I am trying to copy data from a Word document to an Outlook body while keeping formatting. My code pastes the data but loses formatting.

I tried `GetInspector.WordEditor`. I get an error 287 (Application defined or object defined error).

```
Sub openword()

 Dim wdapp As Object
 Dim wddoc As Object
 Dim olapp As Object
 Dim olmail As Object
 Dim myemail As Variant
 Dim str As String
 
 Set wdapp = CreateObject("Word.Application")
 Set wddoc = wdapp.Documents.Open("C:\Users\Ankit.Pandey\Desktop\Templates\DR.docx", ReadOnly:=True)
 
 Set olapp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
 Set olmail = olapp.CreateItem(olMailItem)
      
 With olmail
     .Display
     .To = "a"
     .CC = "b"
     .Subject = "This is a test mail"
     .Body = wddoc.Range
 End With

 Set olapp = Nothing
 Set wdapp = Nothing
 wddoc.Close

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work, I think

```
Sub openword()

  Dim wdapp As Object
  Dim wddoc As Object
  Dim olapp As Object
  Dim olmail As Object
  Dim myemail As Variant
  Dim str As String
  
  '************** Code edited here
  Dim olInspector As Object
  Dim olWordEditor As Object
  '**************
  
  Set wdapp = CreateObject("Word.Application")
  Set wddoc = wdapp.Documents.Open("C:\Users\Ankit.Pandey\Desktop\Templates\DR.docx", ReadOnly:=True)
  
  Set olapp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
  Set olmail = olapp.CreateItem(olMailItem)
  
  
  
  
  With olmail
    .Display
    .To = "a"
    .CC = "b"
    .Subject = "This is a test mail"
    
    '************** Code edited here
    '.Body = wddoc.Range
    Set olInspector = .GetInspector
    Set olWordEditor = olInspector.WordEditor
    wddoc.Range.Copy
    olWordEditor.Range(0, 0).Paste
    '*************
  End With
  
  Set olapp = Nothing
  Set wdapp = Nothing
  wddoc.Close

End Sub
```

Copying and pasting should keep the formatting. Use `Range(0, 0).Paste` rather than `Selection.Paste` to prserve anything that is already there such as your signature.

Comment: Technically this should work but for some reason i get an error 287 every time i try to use  inspector.WordEditor (as i mentioned in my question) i tested your code but it gives me the same error.

Comment: Does it actually work manually? Try this: make `wdapp.Visible = True`. Add a break point at the line `Set olInspector = .GetInspector` and run the code up to the break point. Copy and paste the document contents manually. Then execute the rest of the code. My line of thinking is that this will either highlight the problem in outlook or reset something that will make the rest of the code work.